# TFS runs tests on one agent, but fails on another

Tags: tfs, mstest, tfsbuild

I am setting up TFS for automated build testing.  I have my build controller on the tfs server, and 2 build agents on 2 other machines.  The build completes and all tests pass with the first agent (my local machine).  However, when I switch to my build machine (disabled the agent my machine, enabled the agent on the build machine), the test run does not execute with the following error...

> Test run '...' could not be executed. Failed to queue test run to the controller that collects data and diagnostics: localhost:6901. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:6901

This is screaming permissions issue to me, but I'm not seeing anything that looks like it will fix my problem.  Any ideas where to start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the test settings I had enabled. It had a specified controller to use for the "local execution and remote collection" and was set to collect on my machine.  Hence when I ran the test on the other machine it was trying to open the connection to my machine for the data collection.  I have no data collection going on, so I set it to "local execution".